# SQL: simple summation query with join to 2 other tables

Tags: sqlite, spatialite

I have 3 tables in sqlite as follows:

Table 1

```
ID | x
1, 2.0
2, 3.0
3, 4.0
4, 3.0
```

Table 2

```
join_ID | x
1, 5.0
1, 6.0
2, 5.0
2, 2.0
3, 2.0
4, 2.0
```

Table 3

```
join_ID | x
4, 5.0
1, 6.0
3, 5.0
2, 2.0
2, 2.0
1, 2.0
```

I would like to obtain a table as follows:

```
ID | x | x_agg
1, 2, 21
2, 3, 14
3, 4, 11
4, 3, 10
```

Where `x` represents the sum of all rows containing coinciding ID's. In essence this is the computation I would like to achieve:

row1 --> 2+5+6+6+2 = 21

row2 --> 3+5+2+2+2 = 14

row3 --> 4+2+5 = 11

row4 --> 3+2+5 = 10

I am using sqlite within the DBManager in QGIS (via spatialite). The above is a limited working example I have concocted but should replicate the conditions I am working under. I came up with the following code:

```
 select
  table1.ID,
  ifnull(table1.x,0) as x,
  SUM(ifnull(table2.x,0)) +SUM(ifnull(table3.x,0))+ifnull(table1.x,0) as x_agg
from
 table1
  left join table2 on table1.ID = table2.join_ID
  left join table3 on table1.ID = table3.join_ID
group by
  ID;
```

But instead get:

```
ID  x   x_agg
1   2.0 40.0
2   3.0 25.0
3   4.0 11.0
4   3.0 10.0
```

When I run the above. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to proceed here is to just join to two separate subqueries which aggregate the second and third tables separately:

```
SELECT
    t1.ID,
    t1.x,
    COALESCE(t2.sum_x, 0) + COALESCE(t3.sum_x, 0) AS x_agg
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT join_ID, SUM(x) AS sum_x
    FROM table2
    GROUP BY join_ID
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.join_ID
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT join_ID, SUM(x) AS sum_x
    FROM table3
    GROUP BY join_ID
) t3
    ON t1.ID = t3.join_ID;
```

Note that I use left joins in both places because it could be that a given `ID` from the first table does not appear in either of the two other tables.  In this case, the effective sum should be treated as zero.

Comment: seems to work... what is the difference between `COALESCE` and `IFNULL`? Why are you using `COALESCE` instead of `IFNULL` here?

Comment: @user32882 The only difference between `IFNULL` and `COALESCE` in SQLite is that the former accepts only two arguments, while the latter accepts more than two.  You could replace `COALESCE` with `IFNULL` in my query and it would be the same.

Comment: Fair enough. Accepted.

Comment: That gives me different results than what the OP wanted for the `x_agg` column.

Comment: @Shawn Agreed, but then I don't know what the logic is for aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

What about this one, which adds the sums of the tables all in the row part of the outer SELECT without any joins?

```
SELECT id
     , ifnull(x, 0) as x
     , ifnull(x, 0)
         + (SELECT total(x) FROM table2 AS t2 WHERE t1.id = t2.join_id)
         + (SELECT total(x) FROM table3 AS t3 WHERE t1.id = t3.join_id) AS x_agg
FROM table1 AS t1
ORDER BY id;
id          x           x_agg     
----------  ----------  ----------
1           2           21.0      
2           3           14.0      
3           4           11.0      
4           3           10.0
```

- `sum()` vs `total()`: Both return the sum of all non-null values, but `sum()` returns null and `total()` returns 0.0 for the case where every value is null.

---

Using the following data (Note use of indexes to improve the correlated subqueries):

```
CREATE TABLE table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, x NUMERIC);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(1,2);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(2,3);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(3,4);
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(4,3);
CREATE TABLE table2(join_id INTEGER, x NUMERIC);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(1,5);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(1,6);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(2,5);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(2,2);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(3,2);
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(4,2);
CREATE TABLE table3(join_id INTEGER, x NUMERIC);
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(4,5);
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(1,6);
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(3,5);
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(2,2);
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(2,2);
INSERT INTO table3 VALUES(1,2);
CREATE INDEX table2_join_id_idx ON table2(join_id);
CREATE INDEX table3_join_id_idx ON table3(join_id);
```

Comment: also seems to work, how would you handle null values? All null values in t1, t2 and t3 need to be considered as having a value of 0

Comment: @user32882 If you have to deal with null values, explicitly mentioning that in your question would be nice, as well some sample rows with them... will update, though.

Comment: @user32882 Done.